# Trouble with lifecycle in JSF 2.0 and selectManyListbox

Tags: jsf-2, lifecycle, selectmanylistbox

I am trying to make a simple admin page for managing users list. The jsf code looks like this:

```
 <h:selectOneMenu  id="selectUser" value="#{adminBean.user_id}" valueChangeListener="#{adminBean.userSelected}" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{adminBean.myModelUsersValues}" />   
                    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="login password privilege_list" execute="@this"/>      
                 </h:selectOneMenu > 

   <table>
      <tr>
        <td><h:outputLabel styleClass="LabelStyle" value="login: "/></td>         
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <h:inputText id="login" value="#{adminBean.login}"/>
        </td>   
        <td>
        <h:message for="login" style="color:red"/>
        </td>                        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><h:outputLabel styleClass="LabelStyle" value="password: "/></td>         
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <h:inputText id="password" value="#{adminBean.password}"/>
        </td>   
        <td>
        <h:message for="password" style="color:red"/>
        </td>                      
      </tr>       
      <tr>
        <td><h:outputLabel styleClass="LabelStyle" value="privilege list: "/></td>         
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <h:selectManyListbox  id="privilege_list" value="#{adminBean.privilegeList}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{adminBean.privilegeValues}" />                          
             </h:selectManyListbox > 
        </td>    
        <td>
        <h:message for="privilege_list" style="color:red"/>
        </td>                      
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <h:commandButton id="addButton" value="Add" action="#{adminBean.addUser}" styleClass="ButtonStyle"/>               
    <h:commandButton id="deleteButton" value="Delete" action="#{adminBean.deleteUser}" styleClass="ButtonStyle"/>                  
    <h:commandButton id="clearButton" value="Clear" action="#{adminBean.clear}" styleClass="ButtonStyle"/>
```

The problem is that when the page loads, all the items are empty. Now When I click on 'add' button I have discovered that the `valueChangeListener="#{adminBean.userSelected}"` runs, which replaces my privilege list with the ones from the first user. The same is when I use the clear button - all fields are empty, but when I click on the add button again, the list is the one from the first user (and only the list - no other input texts). I tried adding `immediate="true"` to the add button and that solves this problem, but off course then all the values I put into input text are not passed through to the `adminBean.addUser` action method. My bean is viewscoped (I needed to use it because of the validation error on selectManyListBox). Here is the Java code (the addUser method so far only sends a logger method and checks i login exists, and if sth was selected on the priv. list):

```
@ManagedBean(name="adminBean")
@ViewScoped
public class AdminBean {
private String user_id ="";
private String login ="";
private String password ="";
private ArrayList<String> privilegeList = new ArrayList<String>();

private User model = new User();
private TreeMap<String, User> usersValuesBackendMap = new TreeMap<String, User>();
private TreeMap<String, String> privilegesValues = new TreeMap<String, String>();
private TreeMap<String, String> myModelUsersValues = new TreeMap<String, String>();

...

    @javax.annotation.PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {       

        usersValuesBackendMap = queryDAO.getAllUsers();

        for (Map.Entry<String, User> usr : usersValuesBackendMap.entrySet()) {
            myModelUsersValues.put(usr.getValue().getLogin(), usr.getKey() );
        }

        privilegesValues = queryDAO.getFullPrivilegeList();
        user_id = ""; 
    }
    public void userSelected(ValueChangeEvent event){
           String newValue = event.getNewValue().toString();       

           User user = usersValuesBackendMap.get(newValue);

           login = user.getLogin();
           password = user.getPassword();
           privilegesValues.clear();
           for (String privilege: user.getPrivilegeValues() ){      
               privilegesValues.put(privilege, privilege);
           }
       }

        public String clear(){

            user_id ="";
            login ="";
            password ="";
            privilegesValues = queryDAO.getFullPrivilegeList(); 
            return "";
        }
```

Interestingly I added immediate="true" to the clearing method and then sth. opposite happens - the list is OK but the inputTexts are filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some facts:

1. The `valueChangeListener` runs when `!oldValue.equals(newValue)`.
2. The `valueChangeListener` is **not** a client side event listener. It's entirely server side.
3. The `valueChangeListener` is completely independent on whether it's an ajax or normal request. It's invoked on all types of requests, including the normal form submit.

You need `<a4j:ajax listener>` instead.

```
<h:selectOneMenu  id="selectUser" value="#{adminBean.user_id}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{adminBean.myModelUsersValues}" />   
    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{adminBean.userSelected}" render="login password privilege_list" execute="@this"/>      
</h:selectOneMenu >
```

with

```
public void userSelected(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    User user = usersValuesBackendMap.get(user_id);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hopefully I can still count on some help cause it is about the same project. Your suggestion works, but I have another problem. When I add the user everything works fine and I can see the new one in SelectOneMenu. However when I delete it it is still on the list (although no fields are filled when selected). Off course I update the list in the bean method exactly the same as in the add user action. What can be the problem? I tried switching to a4j:ajax for the buttons but it's the same (plus messages are not sent).